# Why i cant use ufw deny to "Nginx HTTP" from x.x.x.x?

Tags: linux, nginx, firewall, system-administration, ufw

How I may add this rule in my ufw list?

```
ufw deny to "Nginx HTTP" from x.x.x.x
```

And I know about nginx.conf, but this variant does not suit me for one reason.

I tried the command above but it doesn't work. Also I tried banned :80/tcp, but this rule doesn't working for Nginx. Just say me is there such a rule for ufw.

Answer (score 0):

check profile 'Nginx HTTP', it should has ports=

For example:

```
[OpenVPN]
title=OpenVPN server
description=This rule allows connections to VPN server at <servername>.
ports=8880/udp
```

Check profile:

```
sudo ufw app list
sudo ufw app info 'Nginx HTTP'
```

If ok:

```
sudo ufw deny from 1.1.1.1 to any app 'Nginx HTTP'
```